# How to write conditional query with combination of two columns as a single query in Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5

I have three tables `products`, `product_meta_keys`, and `product_meta_values`. Product table stores product's general information like `name` and `product_meta_keys` stores the dynamic features/specification key of product like `product brand` whereas `product_meta_values` table stores the corresponding value for given product and given meta_key. Here are sample table structure:

Product Table

[image]

Product Meta Key table

[image]

Product meta value table

[image]

In this table `product_id` and `meta_key_id` is foreign key from `product` and `product_meta_key` table.

Now, What I want is, to query into `product_meta_values` table to find the product ids using the conditional query with the combination of two column (`meta_key_id` and `meta_value`) as a single condition.

Here is the query that I have tried (Ignore the join part for now):

```
\DB::table('product_meta_values')
    ->select('product_id as product')
    ->where(function($query){
        $query->where('meta_key_id', 1)
              ->where('meta_value', 'MValue 1');
    })
    ->where(function($query){
        $query->where('meta_key_id', 2)
              ->where('meta_value', 'MValue 2');
    })
    ->distinct()
    ->get();
```

[image]

What I expect is

+---------+
| product |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+

But got Empty set. Any idea?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
x1.product_id
FROM
(
    SELECT
        product_id
    from
        meta_values
    where
        (
            meta_key_id = 1
            AND meta_value = 'MValue1'
        )
) as x1 ,
(
    SELECT
        product_id
    from
        meta_values
    where
        (
            meta_key_id = 2
            AND meta_value = 'MValue2'
        )
) as x2
 where
  x1.product_id = x2.product_id
```

The problem with your query was using **AND** with multiple column on a single row, what AND does is strictly search for matching results in a single row. Which is kind of tricky. Try using subqueries for these kinds of problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use joins for these kinds of problems:

```
Product::
join('pmv', 'pmv.product_id', '=', $product->id)->
join('mk', 'pmv.meta_value', '=', 'mk.id')->
where( //add conditions here// )->where('key', '=', 'value')->
select('products.name', 'pmv.field1', 'mk.fieldX')->
get();
```

Where pmv is product_meta_values and mk is meta_keys. Note that you should add the name of the table before you query any field, since you need to tell the query in what table to look for the field.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but did you actually run the query to get the expected result with given condition above?

Comment: Not this query specifically. in the joins you specify which fields should be the same in the different tables, then you can add conditions on everything on those tables using where.

Comment: Joining table is not my actual issue, my main issue is to find the value from a single (`product_meta_values`) with the given condition

Comment: What is the condition, and what fields do you need retrieved?

Comment: I want to write conditional query with the combination of two columns ( `meta_key_id` annd `meta_value`).  For example [ meta_key_id => 1 and meta_value => 'MValue 1'] as one condition and [ meta_key_id => 2 and meta_value => 'MValue 2'] as other condition and I want to retrive product_ids .

Comment: In one 'where' you can only write one condition, you can chain them as I have demonstrated, which will give the same effect.

Comment: Instead of chaining multiple where clause, you can write multiple conditions inside one where clause like 
`\DB::table('product_meta_keys')->where([
['meta_key_id'=>1],['meta_value'=>'MValue 1'],['meta_key_id'=> 2],['meta_value'=>'MValue 2']
])->get();`

But this does not give the expected result. I already tried.